# how to make a Clickmap on a Django application?

Tags: javascript, django, google-analytics, heatmap

`Hello!

I'm building an application with django and I need to make a clickmap/heatmap to get some statistics from my site.

My problem: almost all the forms are out of date and I don't want to use Google Analytics or anything like that.

I need a visual map that shows me where users are clicking, the most accessed pages, etc.

Things i tried:
https://django-analytical.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
clickmap.js
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/setup-and-installation/clarity-setup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/setup-and-installation/clarity-setup%60)